# Good resources for coding forms with jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, form-submit

I've been trolling around for a couple days now looking for some good resources on form validation and submission with jQuery. Of course, I've been able to find some specific blog posts on sites like NetTuts and ThemeForest, but I'm looking for best practice information.

What is the best way(s) to validate user form information? Plugins? From scratch?

Again, I'm looking for best practices, or accepted, methods of validation and submission from the wider community. If you have any specific links or articles, pass it on for us all to peruse.

Thanks!

Comment: quick search on google gave me this page full of info http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of my favorite jQuery form validation plugins has to be [Happy.js](http://happyjs.com/). It's very lightweight and extensible, and requires very little effort to get working.

Comment: +1, thanks for the link. While it's not very full-featured, I think the ID-based approach is much better than the class-based approach that the popular bassistance plugin uses. And its extensibility mechanisms are so simple.

Comment: Happy.js can use classes just fine -- just use the standard jQuery class selectors, e.g. `.email`.

Comment: Ok, I really like Happy.js. Super light-weight, easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to validate with jQuery is to just use the [jQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation). It's widely used, regularly maintained, easy to use and mature. There's no point in rewriting something that's already been done. You can obviously use this plugin to control form submission.

Comment: Yes, I've been tinkering with this plugin since yesterday. It's pretty full featured, but for some reason, I've not been able to get it to work. Do I need to submit the form by running a function in the success area?